# como obtener datos MVVM

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, mvvm

HOLA estoy realizando una una app. Donde tengo un listado y al clickear un lemento navego a otro fragment donde lleno un recyclerview con informacion de la subcoleccion. La coleccion de firebase con MVVM y cada documento de la coleccion tiene una subcoleccion llamada "productos " como puedo hacer el get para que me busque la subcoleccion de cada documento en especifico?  como puedo enviar la informacion desde el fragment hasta el datasource??
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
//ESTO ES EL FRAGMENT
     viewModel.favoristos(id).observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            when (it) {
                is Result.Loading -> {
                    binding.deltarelative.show()


                }
                is Result.Succes -> {
                    binding.detallesO.adapter = adapterDetalles(it.data)
                    binding.deltarelative.hide()

                }
                is Result.Failure -> {
                    binding.deltarelative.hide()

                    Toast.makeText(
                        requireContext(),
                        "ocurrio un error:${it.exception}",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()

                }

            }
        })
//ESTA ES LA IMPLEMENTACION DE LA INTERFACE Y EL DATASOURCE
    class HomeImp(private val data: DataSourceHome):HomeInt {
    override suspend fun Producto(id :String): Result<List<DataSource>> =data.getOferts(id)
//ESTA ES LA INTERFACE
interface HomeInt {
    suspend fun Producto(id :String):Result<List<DataSource>>
//ESTE ES EL DATASOURCE
 suspend fun getPRODUTO(id_:String): Result<List<DataSource>> {
        val listClientes = mutableListOf<DataSource>()
        val data_id = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("comercios/$ID/producto").get().await()
        data_id.forEach {
            val data_it= FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("comercios/${it.id}/ofertas").get().await()
            for(document in data_it.documents){
                document.toObject(DataSource::class.java)?.let { index->
                listClientes.add(index)

            }
        }
        }
//ESTA ES LA CLASE VIEWMODEL DONDE IMPLEMENTO LA INTERFACE
class viewModelPost (private val repo: HomeInt) :ViewModel(){
fun favoristos(id:String) = liveData(Dispatchers.IO) {
        emit(Result.Loading())
        try {
            emit(repo.Producto(id))
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            emit(Result.Failure(e))
        }
    }
```

Comment: como puedo hacer el get para que me busque la subcoleccion de cada documento en especifico? - Si el get te devuelve la colección y cada elemento a su vez tiene su subcolección ya no necesitas un nuevo get.  Entonces al pulsar en el item del fragment puedes pasar por bundle la subcolección de productos para mostrar en la siguiente pantalla.  Otra opción es pasar el id del item, y que el repo después de hacer el get, guarde en caché esos elementos y sea el repo quién reciba el id del item y haga el filter en lugar de pasar todo el objeto por bundle

Comment: como puedo enviar la informacion desde el fragment hasta el datasource?? - Si tienes una arquitectura debes respetarla, entonces quien se comunica con firebase es el datasource, no el fragment, por lo que al iniciar el fragment, el ViewModel pide datos al repo, que los pide al datasource que los pide a firebase.  Al devolverlos, el repo si quieres puede cachear la respuesta y devolverlo.  Incluso puedes crear un modelo de datos en el ViewModel y otro distinto para la respuesta, porque si la api cambia, el ViewModel no debe saberlo.  Un truco, mira que el vm no haya imports del repositorio.

Comment: Gracias por contestar, saber de algun repositorio que pueda chekear ??

Comment: Como puedo completar la query del datasource para que al clikear vaya a la subcoleccion del propio elemento ??

Comment: puedes leer este artículo y revisar el repositorio https://medium.com/dottech/cómo-implementar-una-arquitectura-limpia-en-android-59b7510cef3